# Any idea why the following UIView animation only works in one direction?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, animation, uiview

I have the following animation at the end of my cellForRowAtIndex Delegate method which just shifts all the cells left/right depending on whether i have the pseudoEditing flag set or not:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"cell shift" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kEventActionViewAnimationDuration];

cell.eventName.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kPseudoEditingFirstIndentedRect : kFirstLabelRect;
cell.eventLocationName.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kPseudoEditingSecondIndentedRect : kSecondaryLabelRect;
cell.eventStartDate.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kPseudoEditingThirdIndentedRect : kThirdLabelRect;
cell.eventStartEndTime.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kPseudoEditingFourthIndentedRect : kFourthLabelRect;
cell.imageView.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kImageViewIndentedRect : kImageViewRect;
cell.rsvpImageView.hidden = !self.pseudoEditing;

[UIView commitAnimations];


return cell;
```

Here is where the constants are declared:

```
#define kImageViewRect                          CGRectMake(10, 9.0, 60.0, 60.0)
#define kFirstLabelRect                         CGRectMake(80, 10.0, 220.0, 20.0)
#define kSecondaryLabelRect                     CGRectMake(80, 30.0, 220.0, 20.0)
#define kThirdLabelRect                         CGRectMake(80, 50.0, 220.0, 20.0)
#define kFourthLabelRect                        CGRectMake(180.0, 50.0, 110.0, 20.0)

#define kPseudoEditingFirstIndentedRect         CGRectMake(115.0, 10.0, 195.0, 20.0)
#define kPseudoEditingSecondIndentedRect        CGRectMake(115.0, 30.0, 195.0, 20.0)
#define kPseudoEditingThirdIndentedRect         CGRectMake(115.0, 50.0, 195.0, 20.0)
#define kPseudoEditingFourthIndentedRect        CGRectMake(200.0, 50.0, 110.0, 20.0)
```

The problem is that it only works in one direction when shifting back from right to left and *not* from the normal state from left to right.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to set up the animation?

Comment: You should probably try Block animations instead, as they are easier, and the Apple approved way of doing things.

Comment: @MSgambel: Apple "approves" of both methods.  Perhaps you mean using blocks is the preferred method?

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: Yes, that is what I mean. After iOS 4.0, Apple prefers you use blocks to do your animations.

Comment: @XenElement, not sure what you mean but that is all the animation code i am using. re:others, need backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my FetchedResultsController was reloading the table directly after the animation began which cancelled it out.